# How to write N bits to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, rtp

I have a task to decode an RTP packet and extract the payload of this packet (audio data). In order to bypass all the RTP header fields, I have this function:

```
quint32 readNBitsByRange(quint32 position, quint32 count, const QByteArray &array)
{
    quint32 accuml = 0;
    while (count != 0) {
            const quint32 l = (8 - position % 8);
            const quint32 u = (l < count ? l : count);
            const quint32 f = (8 - u);
            accuml  <<= u;
            accuml   |= ((*(array.data() + position / 8) << (8 - l)) & (((1 << u) - 1) << f)) >> f;
            position += u;
            count    -= u;
    }
    return accuml;
}
```

As arguments, the function takes the position from which the read will be made, the number of bits, and the buffer from which the read should be made. Thanks to this function, I can read all the RTP header fields. Example of using this function:

```
int main()
{
    // ... We get The RTP packet in binary form and write it to QByteArray ...
    QByteArray array;
    for (quint32 i = 0; i < rtpBinaryDataLength; ++i) {
        array.push_back(rtpBinaryData[i]);
    }
    
    // 0                   1                   2                   3
    // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    // |V=2|P|X|  CC   |M|     PT      |       sequence number         |
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    // |                           timestamp                           |
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    // |           synchronization source (SSRC) identifier            |
    // +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
    // |            contributing source (CSRC) identifiers             |
    // |                             ....                              |
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    
    quint16 rtpVersion   = readNBitsByRange(0x000, 0x002, array);
    quint16 rtpPadding   = readNBitsByRange(0x002, 0x001, array);
    quint16 rtpExtension = readNBitsByRange(0x003, 0x001, array);
    
    // .. And so on ...
}
```

It all works! But here's the problem! Now I have a task to write the RTP packet values to QByteArray. I don't know how to do it! We only know that, for example, the values of 4 fields (V, P, X, CC) of the RTP packet must be written to the 1st byte of the buffer.

I would like to have an example function, like for reading, so that you can easily work with it. Example of a function:

```
void writeNBits(quint32 position, quint32 count, quint32 val, QByteArray &array)
{
   // ...
}
```

I tried writing all the values to the header, and then just write them to the QByteArray:

```
struct RtpHeader
{
    unsigned m_v :2; 
    unsigned m_p :1; 
    unsigned m_x :1; 
    unsigned m_cc:4; 
    unsigned m_m :1; 
    unsigned m_pt:7; 
    uint16_t m_sn;   
    uint32_t m_tm;   
    uint32_t m_ssrc;   
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RtpHeader hdr;
    
    hdr.m_v    = 2;
    hdr.m_p    = 0;
    hdr.m_x    = 0;
    hdr.m_cc   = 0;
    hdr.m_m    = 1;
    hdr.m_pt   = 8;
    hdr.m_sn   = 59133;
    hdr.m_tm   = 240;
    hdr.m_ssrc = 0xDEE0EE8F;

    QByteArray array(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&hdr), sizeof(hdr));
    for (quint8 i = 0; i < 240; i++) {
        array.push_back(0xD5); // Silence 
    }

    QFile file("./rawRtpPacket.bin");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(array);
    file.close();
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But that's not what I should get!
For example, I should have received these results of a 12-byte header :

```
80 88 E6 FD  00 00 00 F0  DE E0 EE 8F
```

But I get different results:

```
02 11 FD E6  F0 00 00 00  8F EE E0 DE
```

If you look closely, from 4 bytes to 12, I have to mirror these values, but at the expense of the first two bytes, I can't understand why I get a completely different one.

I write: V-2, P-0, X-0, CC-0 and should get `10000000`, but I get `00000010`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting a bit, I found a more correct way to write the `RTP` packet in `QByteArray` and realized my previous errors. Therefore, I wrote a sample version of the correct `RTP` packet entry in `QByteArray`:

```
class RtpHeader
{
public:

    quint16 m_vp:0x02;
    quint16 m_pf:0x01;
    quint16 m_xf:0x01;
    quint16 m_cc:0x04;
    quint16 m_mb:0x01;
    quint16 m_pt:0x07;
    quint16 m_sn;
    quint32 m_tm;
    quint32 m_ss;

};

class RtpHeaderEncoder
{
public:

    RtpHeaderEncoder(void)                                noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder &operator=(const RtpHeaderEncoder &) noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder &operator=(RtpHeaderEncoder &&)      noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder(const RtpHeaderEncoder &)            noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder(RtpHeaderEncoder &&)                 noexcept = delete;
   ~RtpHeaderEncoder(void)                                noexcept = delete;

    static QByteArray encode(const RtpHeader &hdr)  noexcept;

};

QByteArray RtpHeaderEncoder::encode(const RtpHeader &hdr) noexcept
{
    QByteArray array;

    if ((hdr.m_vp == 0x02) && (hdr.m_pf == 0x00) && (hdr.m_cc <= 0x0F) && (hdr.m_pt <= 0x12)) {

        QDataStream stream(&array, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        stream << (((hdr.m_vp & 0x00003) << 0x01E)|
                   ((hdr.m_pf & 0x00001) << 0x01D)|
                   ((hdr.m_xf & 0x00001) << 0x01C)|
                   ((hdr.m_cc & 0x0000F) << 0x018)|
                   ((hdr.m_mb & 0x00001) << 0x017)|
                   ((hdr.m_pt & 0x0007F) << 0x010)|
                   ((hdr.m_sn & 0x0FFFF) << 0x000));

        stream << hdr.m_tm << hdr.m_ss;
    }
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RtpHeader hdr;
    hdr.m_vp = 2;
    hdr.m_pf = 0;
    hdr.m_xf = 0;
    hdr.m_cc = 0;
    hdr.m_mb = 0;
    hdr.m_pt = 8;
    hdr.m_sn = 1;
    hdr.m_tm = 201452158;
    hdr.m_ss = 111537764;

    QFile file("./rawRtpHeader.bin");
    file.open (QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(RtpHeaderEncoder::encode(hdr));
    file.close();
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This method is both more secure and guarantees that all fields of the [fixed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-5.1) `RTP` packet header are filled in correctly. If you need to fill `QByteArray` and [payload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_payload_formats), then just after filling the array with the package header, we write the payload itself.

P.S. If there are any questions or comments related to the code, I will be happy to answer and accept the criticism.